# Provide a list of targets to add_custom_command in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a simple CMakeLists.txt which makes two different targets and copies across a file which the source code uses to read in some data. While the targets are different, the data file is the same.

```
add_executable(
  tiny-ewg
  "src/tiny-ewg.cpp"
)

add_executable(
  tiny-ewg-improved
  "src/tiny-ewg-improved.cpp"
)
 
add_custom_command(
TARGET tiny-ewg POST_BUILD
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/tiny-ewg.txt
${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tiny-ewg.txt
)

add_custom_command(
TARGET tiny-ewg-improved POST_BUILD
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/tiny-ewg.txt
${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tiny-ewg.txt
)
```

I am not satisfied with the code reuse here. I wondered if it is possible to pass a list of the targets to `add_custom_command` or some other cmake command. I was hoping I could do something like this, but it is unfortunately not valid CMake:

```
add_custom_command(
TARGET set(tiny-ewg tiny-ewg-improved) POST_BUILD
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/tiny-ewg.txt
${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tiny-ewg.txt
)
```

Comment: seems like a job for a [macro](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html) if you want to do the same thing twice